# Не срабатывает валидация по типу поля в Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Нужно дополнить сериализатор на проверку типа поля - например, если вместо строки приходит число.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    # others fields ...
    my_field: serializers.CharField = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=300, required=True, error_messages=REQUIRED_CHAR_FIELD


    def validate_my_field(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not valid")
        return value
```

Почему-то validate_my_field не срабатывает - условие не выполняется, если value = 5. Делал всё, как в [документации](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

Comment: а приходит точно число? а не допустим строка "5"? Если у вас поле `CharField` вам и придет строка, даже если вы ввели число.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin , вы правы, 5 воспринимается как строка. Большое спасибо!